# DC motor, disadvantage of having independent coils

Tags: dc-motor, winding

My knowledge in electrical motors is not that good.

In first pic, when the coil is vertical, torque is \$0\$, but inertia keeps it spinning counterclockwise.  I get this.

With only one coil, the torque is uneven. To fix this we add more coils and increase the segments on commutator.

In the second pic, the current is flowing in  only one coil at a time. The other coil has no current and waits its turn.

This arrangement looks simple, but does anyone manufacture motors like this?
Are there any disadvantages?

(I'm asking because, I've opened few toy motors and seen many videos.. they all use a more complicated arrangement of coils: lap/wave winding where current flows all over, and a bit hard to follow for me)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why not put the coils in the stator, then you get much better and finer control.

Comment: do you mean in a high magnetic permeable cylinder? i guess so, but first i want to understand the basic electrical connections between commutator segments and coils...

Comment: Your question doesn't really have an answer, does anyone manufacture motors like this, most likely there is someone, somewhere on earth that manufacture a motor like this with 2 only coils.

Comment: Haha @Damien I meant if any known manufacturer in industry like ABB etc manufacture this and has any applications where this arrangement works well.. On some thinking, I feel this is just a duplex lap winding..

Comment: On an industrial scale, most likely not, motor always have several set of windings, but maybe in some specific applications, like vibrators inside phones,... you never know and you can probably find all sorts of exotic coil structure.

Answer (score 1):

It is not likely that anyone would make a DC motor with two coils in the way shown. The simplest DC motor that is actually manufactured has a three segment commutator with three coils connected in series with the commutator segments connected to the connection points between the coils. Those are found in a lot of toys, but they have also been used in some kinds of battery operated appliances.